# clojure.java.io ClassNotFoundException

Tags: clojure

I am trying to run the following program on my Mac:

```
(ns clojure.examples.hello
   (:gen-class))
(require ‘clojure.java.io’)
(defn Example []
   (.exists (file "Example.txt")))
(Example)
```

I do this wih the following command:

```
clojure Exists.clj
```

But this gives me the following error:

```
Syntax error (ClassNotFoundException) compiling at (Exists.clj:5:1).
‘clojure.java.io’
```

How can I go about including the clojure.java.io class?

Comment: You have too many quotes in the vicinity of clojure.java.io. When quoting a Lisp symbol with the apostrophe, you use only ONE apostrophe, to prefix the symbol.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you would normally write this in a source code file:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require [clojure.java.io :as io]) ; proper form, but not used anywhere
  (:import [java.io File]))

(println (spit "demo.txt" "stuff happens"))
(println (slurp "demo.txt"))
(println (.exists (java.io.File. "./demo.txt"))) ; will work w/o `:import` above
(println (.exists (File. "./demo.txt"))) ; requires `:import` declaration above
```

with results:

```
(spit "demo.txt" "stuff happens")        => nil
(slurp "demo.txt")                       => "stuff happens"
(.exists (java.io.File. "./demo.txt"))   => true
(.exists (File. "./demo.txt"))           => true
```

Note that using the `:require` keyword in a `ns` form requires different syntax and quoting than using the `(require ...)` function call.

If you are typing these lines into a REPL, you may do something like:

```
demo.core=> (ns demo.core)
nil
demo.core=> (require '[clojure.java.io :as io])   ; function-call version
nil
demo.core=> (spit "demo.txt" "stuff happens")
nil
demo.core=> (println (slurp "demo.txt"))
stuff happens
nil
```

You may find [this template project](https://github.com/io-tupelo/clj-template) helpful in getting started.  Also be sure to check out the list of documentation sources, esp. the Clojure CheatSheet!